# Im not able to route to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import CreateBug from './CreateBug';
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App(history) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleOnClick = () => navigate('/createBug');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug />} />
      </Routes>
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          BUGHOUND
        </p>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleOnClick()}>
          Create a bug
        </Button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

On click of that create bug button in app.js, `CreateBug` page should be rendered. which is the below code.

CreactBug.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function CreateBug() {
  const [newBugDescription, setNewBugDescription] = useState;

  return (
    <div>
      New Bug Report Entry Page
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="newBugDescription">
          New Bug Description:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="newBugDescription"
          value={newBugDescription}
          onChange={event => setNewBugDescription(event.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateBug
```

I'm not able to route to create bug page, please help me with this. I have attached the error screenshot with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are **3** problems in ur code 
**1: while using the onClick property in app.js** 
u wrote 
`onClick = {handleOnClick()}`
which is incorrect, The correct method is

```
onClick = {handleOnClick}          just specify the name of the function 
onClick = {() => handleOnClick()}  call the function inside an arrow function
```

**2:the second problem is**  
there is no () after the useState in CreateBug.js

**3: The third problem is**  
the incorrect use of browser router
u are suppsoed to wrap all ur divs where u want the routing to take place into a  tag and then specify the  isndie them 
i will attach the correct code below

**INDEX.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter, Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import CreateBug from './CreateBug';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App/>} />
      <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug />} />
  </Routes >
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**APP.JS**

```
import './App.css';
import CreateBug from './CreateBug';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleOnClick = () => navigate('/createBug');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <p>BUGHOUND</p>
      <button variant="contained" onClick={handleOnClick}>Create a bug</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

createbug.js remains same as given

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are importing the `BrowserRouter` as `Route` and improperly using it.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
```

## Solution

Import and router and render it higher in the ReactTree than any component that is trying to access the routing context value it provides.

Import the `BrowserRouter` in `index.js` and wrap the `App` component.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Import `Routes` and `Route` in `App.js`. ***Don't*** immediately invoke the `handleClick` function, i.e. use `onClick={handleOnClick}` instead of `onClick={handleOnClick()}`.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import CreateBug from './CreateBug';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleOnClick = () => navigate('/createBug');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug />} />
      </Routes>
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          BUGHOUND
        </p>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleOnClick}>
          Create a bug
        </Button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `CreateBug` component also should invoke the `useState` hook, i.e. `useState("")` instead of just `useState`.

```js
const [newBugDescription, setNewBugDescription] = useState("");
```